# Unresolved external symbol in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::rand;
int man(){


    int t=rand();
    cout<<t<<endl;


     return 0;
}
```

here is code    for generate random number in c++ and i have mistake

```
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\random_function\Debug\random_function.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

please help

Comment: Try fixing the type: It is `main`, not `man`.

Comment: +1 don't know why people downvote this question, its ok to ask, just need a bit more detail.

Comment: Although you would think vs2010 might notice there is no main() in your project and inform you of that rather more politely

Comment: @Martin Beckett it usually says " : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main" before the line OP copy-pasted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me, I think I'd change "man" to "main" and see what happens...

Answer (score 8):

Change `man()` to `main()`.